# How to solve SQL Error: ORA-00904: "R"."TENANT_NO": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

How to solve this error and why there comes out the yellow line ?

I tried to rewrite the JOIN statement but still doesn't work

Comment: @Abra, of course you can use the same alias twice - it is just the same as if you used the same **table** twice. You'll just produce a self-join.

Answer (score 0):

There's no table nor alias whose name is `R` so Oracle can't find that column.

Apart from that, query looks wrong.

- what is `title`? If that's column name which contains e.g. `Mr.` or `Mrs.`, then you don't enclose it into single quotes. Even if it is just a string, there's no point in `to_char`-ing something that already is a char
- `group by` clause has to contain all non-aggregated columns, and you can't use alias in there - you have to specify all columns you concatenated into `tenant_name` separately

Presuming that self-join of the `damage` table is *wrong*, query you might be looking for is

```
  SELECT t.tenant_no,
         t.title || ' ' || t.tenant_givname || ' ' || t.tenant_famname   AS tenant_name,
         TO_CHAR (SUM (d.damage_cost), '$9990.00')                       AS total_cost_of_damages
    FROM rent.damage d
         JOIN rent.tenant t
            ON     t.tenant_no = d.tenant_no
               AND t.rent_agreement_no = d.rent_greement_no
   WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM d.damage_datetime) = 2022
GROUP BY t.tenant_no,
         t.title,
         t.tenant_givname,
         t.tenant_famname
ORDER BY total_cost_of_damages DESC, tenant_no ASC;
```

Though, without tables' description, it is difficult to guess what you want.